# IDE renaming V2

Tags: java, syntax, refactoring

I know that IDEs allow for this type of refactoring:

changing:

```
public String getDisplayName() { return name }
// usage: player.getDisplayName();
```

to

```
public String getCharacterDisplayName() { return name }
// usage: player.getCharacterDisplayName();
```

but is there a tool which will change all external usage of the code getDisplayName()

to this: ?

```
public HashMap<String, String> getArgHandler() {
  return args; //name now stored under key "displayname" ( <"displayname", name>
}
//usage: player.getArgHandler().get("displayname");
```

i.e not renaming a method, but forcing a machine to change every getDisplayName() method to another method completely?

Comment: Asking for tools recommendation is off-topic here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: "What topics can I ask here?" > "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is"

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: Not asking for which tools is better, asking if any tool exists

Comment: Asking "which tool should I use?" falls in this category of off-topic

Comment: That's not even in the OP, read it again. It says "is there a tool"

Comment: Which means "is there a tool I can use?", so you're asking us to *recommend* a tool :)

Comment: So all questions like `How do I create XLS file in Java?` should be closed since that is asking for a tool?

Answer (score 0):

First refactor getDisplayName() to something globally unique/random like `getDisplayNameQWE123()`. Then you can safely use simple text replace to replace `getDisplayNameQWE123()` with `player.getArgHandler().get("displayname")`. Still the `getCharacterDisplayName()` looks better in code than some map with magic keys.

Comment: Thanks, but I have getDisplayName() spread over 100 files, whats the quickest way to use simple text replace to do this for text over all those files?

Comment: Any IDE I know has such ability, even most text editors like Notepad++ can do that.

Comment: I'm using eclipse, do you know what the option is called? All I can find with renaming items is the refactoring tool